# What does the Eclipse console scroll lock button do?

Tags: eclipse

Im pretty sure i know what its supposed to do, but enabling/disabling makes absolutely no difference in my eclipse setup (3.6).
New output still scrolls the console even if i am not positioned to show the last screen full.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [bug 316981](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=316981):

> We have found an understandable but unexpected issue with the scroll lock
>   feature, by exposing it via SSH to the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
X=1
while true ; do
  X=`expr $X + 1`
  echo "Hello $X"
done
```

> Running this script, the "scroll lock" feature does not work.
>   The problem with the test case is that new lines are printed so quickly, that the Terminal
>   Widget's buffer runs over.
>
> Fix:

```
Window > Preferences > Terminal : 
Set "Terminal Buffer" to 100000 lines
```

> Now, scroll lock works as expected even with this case (until 100000 lines are
>   reached).

Comment: Yeh but when you run lots and lots of tests w/ log=debug even 200k overflows...What has the buffer overflowing got to do with scrolling ? Couldnt the cursor remain stuck at line1 col1...and not scroll.

Comment: It would have to pause the program then. But perhaps, that would be better as right now one cannot copy/paste from a console buffer that is rolling over unless the program stops logging long enough to select/copy! (In my case I cannot copy/paste and barely read something in the moving console.) They obviously want people to log to file :)